# how to make column2 second row becomes first row while all other columns stays the same

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My table now

[image]

the above picture shows how my table looks like after select from sql. I wish to eliminate the first row of the time column move all rows up of the time column by one row. like the picture below.desired table Please advice. Any advice that would help is welcome.

[image]

code:

```
<?php
require_once 'db.php';
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
$arr = array();

$sql = ("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE idvisit=384 ORDER BY server_time ASC ");
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("ERROR :" .mysqli_error($conn));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    $arr[] = $row['time_spent'];
    echo "<br>";
}
    $fruit = array_shift($arr);
    print_r($arr);
    echo $arr;

?>
```

Comment: Do you want to delete row from the database or dont want to show the row on output?

Comment: @ImranAbdurRahim I wish to show the row on output...

Comment: check the answer

Comment: This makes no sense. If you have four records with an ID and ID 2 represents the record with 02:00, why do you want to show 22:02 for this ID in the results?

Comment: What is your DBMS? PostgreSQL? Oracle? ... Please add the appropriate tag to your question.

Comment: Please don't use images. Paste the tables as text. That is easier to work with and some of us cannot see pictures.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I am using piwik(piwik.org) to trace visitors on our website and also for employment purposes. Everyone who views any of the link, pages from the website, time is record, when? and where, ip address etc. Piwik database always put 00:00:00 as the first time_spent for the first click, after 6 months of research, because of the mechanism, time is recorded that way by piwik. It is now up to the developer to eliminate that error. . . which there is nothing wrong with the database, we developers have to be more creative....

Comment: @ThorstenKettner there is nothing wrong with this image, if would be no different if I put text and increase the font size???? whats the different?????

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 in order to understand why to use text instead of images in stackoverflow.

Comment: As to the request: can't you simply delete all records from the table where time = 00:00 (``delete from mytable where `time` = time '00:00'``)? Or only select all other records (``select * from mytable where `time` <> '00:00'``). For the select you can even write a view, so you don't have to write that `WHERE` clause in every query.

Comment: I've added a "mysql" tag for you, as according to their FAQ piwik only works with MySQL: https://piwik.org/faq/how-to-install/faq_55/.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thanks for the reply, If I use delete, it will delete all first row of the table, but thats not what I want, if you look at the sample above, table 1 and the desired table, I only wish to delete the first row of the time column. Thanks for the reply again.

Comment: thank you everyone for the wonderful contribution you guys are awesome....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First store the result into an array then remove first item from the array.

**Sample Code:**

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $data[] = $row;
}
array_shift($data); //array_shift() remove first element of an array
```

Now run another loop if you want to grab result of each row. If you want to show it in table, here is a sample loop with html table.

```
echo "<table><tbody>";
forach($data as $item){
   echo "<tr><td>";
   echo $item['column_name'];
   echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</tbody></table>";
```

Now, in the table it will show the result without first row from database.

Comment: thank you, would the script look like this? 

`$data[0] = $row['time']; `

Comment: I only need to remove the first row on the time column, the rest of the columns stay the same....

Comment: No, You have to use like that `$data[0]['time']` `$data[1]['time']` or you can use a loop

and yes,  it will remove first column

Comment: Thank you for your help, this approach eliminates the first row, however it cannot display inside a table. . . if `print_r($data);` is displayed inside the while loop, there will be an error since `array_shift();` is required. Which `array_shift($data)` cannot be included in a while loop.

Comment: Can you please show me your code? i think you are missing something

Comment: I just edited the question and added the code, please advice

Comment: You dont need to take variable for `array_shift()` just simply keep it like `array_shift($arr);`  
And question is, what you really want to show? This code will eliminate first row from result. 
if you want show the result, run another loop . check my updated code

Comment: Thanks Imran, what I really want to show is portrait through the 2 tables show in my questions, to only eliminate the first row of the time column. This means that row2 becomes row1...row(n) becomes row(n-1), while other columns and their rows on the table remain as they are... I hope this would help. The `array_shift()` works by putting it inside the while loop gives only `Array()` as outcome for all rows. Please advice.

Comment: Sorry for the interruption again, it looks like it prints it right outside the `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);` but because I wish to print it inside the table and the table is also inside the while loop. pls advice

Comment: there is no relation between while loop and table. With while loop, just grab result into an array then output the array inside of a table. check my code again.

Comment: Thanks again...I have checked the code again, this really helps...thank you once again